# plot data from a pandas dataframe in a line graph

Tags: python, pandas

I have the folowing dataframe in pandas.
The **date** are two diffrent dates, in this case the 16th and 17th
**Time** will go from 00:00 to 24:00 after that it will be the next day :-)
And **percentage** will go from 100 to 0.

```
    date        time      percentage
   2018-08-16  00:00      36   
   2018-08-16  00:01      37   
   2018-08-16  00:01      38   
   2018-08-16  00:03      39   
   2018-08-16  00:03      40   
   2018-08-16  00:04      41   
   2018-08-16  00:05      42   
   2018-08-16  00:05      43   
   2018-08-16  00:06      44   
   2018-08-16  00:07      45   
   2018-08-16  00:07      46   
   2018-08-16  00:08      47
...
   2018-08-17  07:24      95   
   2018-08-17  07:25      94   
   2018-08-17  07:25      94   
   2018-08-17  07:32      95   
   2018-08-17  07:43      96   
   2018-08-17  07:52      97  
...
```

Now i would like to plot this dat in a line graph like this:

[image]

Tried something with:

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.groupby('time')['percentage'].plot(legend=True)

plt.show()
```

But alway retrurn with a "TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot"

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What is the dtype of 'percentage'? df['percentage'] = pd.to_numeric(df['percentage'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.set_index([df.groupby(['date','time']).cumcount(), 'date', 'time'])['percentage']\
  .unstack('date').reset_index(0, drop=True).sort_index().plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
df.percentage=df.percentage.astype(int)
for i in df.date.unique():
    aux=df[df.date==i]
    plt.plot(aux.time,aux.percentage)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Still get the error "TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot"

Comment: Probably percentage isn't numeric. Can you check if it is being displayer as "30%" instead of 30 or 0.3 ?

Comment: If i print the dateframe they are like 36, 37, 38, 39 etc.
when using "df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)"
it work but it comes with a warning "FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated"

Comment: Try what I posted with the edited version and tell me if it works, please

Comment: Jeah superb! one question is it possible to set a tomestamp per hour on the x-as, at this moment it show "time" would like to get it per hour?

Comment: Check my new answer, that should show you time labels in your x-axis